# JavaScript/jQuery - working with multiple arrays with different data structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, javascript-objects

in my project I need to work with lot of data stored in arrays. I have never done something like this. I know that I can use frameworks for it, but I would like to learn how to I can deal with with it myself.

**Situation**

I have (20 and more) arrays (1000 and more lines each) like this (there are a lot of more items in each row).

```
var travels = [
      ["Johnson Mayer", "21. 3. 2017", "10 km", "100 USD"],
      ["Johnson Mayer", "21. 2. 2017", "20 km", "100 USD"]
    ]

var flights = [
  ["Delta", "Mayer.Johnson", "3. 2017", "10 miles", "200 USD"],
  ["UA", "McRurgh.Steve", "5. 2017", "20 miles", "100 USD"]
]
```

- Arrays have diferent units and data formats (km and miles, name is
  once Name Surname but in second array Surname.Name).
- Similar data are in different positions (travels have name on first position,
  flights on second).
- Some arrays have items that other not
  (airline name for example)
- Not each array contain same things (in
  travels theres not Steve and Mayer is stored twice).

**Goal**

The goal is to see activity of users.

1) I need to load all names from my arrays, merge names because different data structure and store each name as unique "variable". 
*Variable is in quotes because I don't know if I should create simple variable, object, array or something different.*

2) Compare if its date in row qunique - if yes, create new row, if not fill already existing row and merge same data. If I should table from data above, it will be look like this. (Johnson Mayer was merged with Mayer.Johnson, March was merged, 10km and 10miles was transfered into kms and sumarized).

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Distance sum</th>
        <th>Sales</th>
        <th>Airlines</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Johnson Mayer</td>
            <td>2. 2017</td>
            <td>20 km</td>
            <td>100$</td>
            <td>None</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Johnson Mayer</td>
            <td>3. 2017</td>
            <td>26 km</td>
            <td>300$</td>
            <td>Delta</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Steve McRurhg</td>
            <td>5. 2015</td>
            <td>32 km</td>
            <td>100$</td>
            <td>UA</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Questions**

1) How should I work with so much data? I tried render it as table with javascript. Not even rendering, my browser becomes very slow after it was displayed.

2) What is the best way to store data that I get from my arrays? One huge array, multiple arrays, objects?

3) Could you provide me sample code for you solution please?

Comment: This is quite a complex, multi-faceted question. For example, merging `Johnson Mayer` to `Mayer.Johnson` will require a regex in itself -- then there's the fact that they're in different arrays that have differing lengths. You also don't appear to have tried to solve much of your complex problem yourself. Can you please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing the specific problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Show us what you tried that is show

Comment: With a big amount of data, there must be a pagination option when getting data. If you can get, for example, 20 record per request, then parts of your problem can be solved (browser will not have to heavily process data and you can store data into 1 variable, next page action will replace that variable with new data). If the data come from 3rd-party resource, you can try to find if they support pagination.

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell us more about the data sources?

It sounds like a lot of on the fly data parsing. I would consider running a cron job at regular intervals (every 15 minutes) which processes the data and stores it in a database.

Alternatively, the data can be loaded asynchronously with AJAX which would make it possible to produce an accurate preloader or display data gradually as it is loaded.

This answer is assuming that the different arrays are coming from different feeds of live data. I might modify it if this is not the case.